# Cpu usage from top command

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php5, cpu-usage

How can i get the result like example following. Any command or scripts?

```
Snapshot
u1234 3971 1.9 0.0 0 0 ? Z 20:00 0:00 [php] <defunct>
u1234 4243 3.8 0.2 64128 43064 ? D 20:00 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1234/public_html/index.php
u1234 4289 5.3 0.2 64128 43064 ? R 20:00 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1234/public_html/index.php
u1234 4312 9.8 0.2 64348 43124 ? D 20:01 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1234/public_html/index.php
u1235 4368 0.0 0.0 30416 6604 ? R 20:01 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1235/public_html/index.php
u1236 4350 2.0 0.0 34884 13284 ? D 20:01 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1236/public_html/index.php
u1237 4353 13.3 0.1 51296 30496 ? S 20:01 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1237/public_html/index.php
u1238 4362 63.0 0.0 0 0 ? Z 20:01 0:00 [php] <defunct>
u1238 4366 0.0 0.1 51352 30532 ? R 20:01 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1238/public_html/index.php
u1239 4082 3.0 0.0 0 0 ? Z 20:00 0:01 [php] <defunct>
u1239 4361 26.0 0.1 49104 28408 ? R 20:01 0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/u1239/public_html/index.php
u1240 1980 0.4 0.0 0 0 ? Z 19:58 0:00 [php] <defunct>
CPU TIME = 8459.71999999992
```

This result i got from hostgator support :)

I was used "top -c" but they do not show "/home/u1239/public_html/index.php
Thanks

Comment: I'd guess it's an output from `ps`, though I can't say which of its countless options were used.

Comment: That output also assumes you're server is using CGI (I.E. each script is it's own process), if you're using mod_php `top` will probably just show the usage for the `httpd` processes

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be the output of something like this:

```
# ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsize,size,tty,state,etime,cputime,command | grep [p]hp
```